# Porque pierdo datos al recargar la pagina JAVA WEB

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, netbeans-8.2

soy nuevo en esto de hibernate y spring mvc, he logrado mostrar los datos de la tabla "usuarios", la primera vez que cargo la URL Si me muestra los datos, pero al recargar desaparecen.

[image: primera vez que llamo la url]

[image: la segunda vez que llamo la url]

codigo de la clase modelo "UsuariosModelo"

[image: codigo modelo]

Codigo del controlador "UsuarioController"
[image: codigo controlador]

Comment: por favor añade el código en formato de texto, seleccionalo y luego dale clic al ícono `{}`

Answer (score 0):

Solucion encontrada:   el problema se debia que la variable global "Session" tiene que ir dentro del metodo, al parecer al volver a llamar al metodo.